# Six fast days? What's the sixth?

Tags: prayer-book, fast-days

On Mekor Judaica's website, I see a [Sephardic siddur for sale](http://www.mekorjudaica.com/store/detail.asp?ProdID=22469), for the שש תעניות, the six fast days.

I was only aware of 5 fast days:

- Ta'anit Esther
- Tzom Gedaliah
- 10th of Tevet
- 17th of Tammuz
- Tisha B'av

What's the sixth? What does this siddur have that's special for this sixth fast day?

[image: "Seder Shesh Ta'aniyot"]

> ### Collection of
>
> ## Six Fasts
>
> #### New and complete
>
> #### Missing nothing
>
> including
>
> #### Fast of speech
>
> with
> Exegeses of the Sages on the Destruction of the First and Second Temples
> *Midrash Eicha* and exegesis on the coming of the Messiah
>
> A publication of Bakal. Jerusalem 5755

Comment: Here's an example of [Chamesh Taaniyot (5 fasts)](http://www.mekorjudaica.com/store/detail.asp?ProdID=22532) like I would have expected.

Comment: I would guess it's Behab

Comment: Since this is Sephardic Sefer, I think some Sephardim fast Zayin Adar.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Perhaps it includes the [Fast of the Firstborn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_of_the_Firstborn). Contemporary practice is to override it, so I don't know if there's any liturgy for it, but maybe at some time in some communities, it was/is observed as a fast, with its own liturgy.

Or maybe the sixth fast is the non-calendar-fixed "[Ta'anit Dibbur](http://www.ravaviner.com/2010/02/taanit-dibbur.html)," which the front cover says is included.

Comment: +1 That seems to be exactly what the cover indicates, anticipating this question.

Comment: Liturgy for a Taanit Dibbur sounds rather parodoxical...

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps it includes Yom Kippur

Answer (score 0):

There are **6** fast days that every Jew must keep - Tzom Gedaliah, **Yom Kippur**, Asarah B'Teves, Ta'anis Esther, Shivah Asar B'Tammuz and Tishah B'Av. End of story.

Comment: And you propose that the book included full liturgy for Yom Kippur? Also who said these are all fasts that *every* Jew must keep?

Comment: How is this different from Gershon's answer?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya.  I'm so used to Yom Kippur getting its own book that it wouldn't have occurred to me to add it to a different siddur.